# Regex JavaScript overlapping matches

Tags: javascript, regex

If I have a string like `fooba` and I want to catch both `foo` and `fooba` how can I do? If I use `foo|fooba` it cathes only the first `foo` and not `fooba`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lookaheads (zero-width assertion) for both patterns:

```
(?=(foo))(?=(fooba))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aS9hR0/12)

Comment: I can't use match , only exec function

Comment: Even using `exec` button you can use captured groups same way.

Comment: Using `exec` you can do: `var m = /(?=(foo))(?=(fooba))/.exec('fooba');` then use `m[1]` and `m[2]`

Comment: Thanks, what is in m[0]? I have an empty string in it.

Comment: `m[0]` is supposed to be whole match and since we have nothing here except lookaheads therefore `m[0]` is empty. If you change regex to `/(?=(foo))(?=(fooba)).*/` then you will get `fooba` in `m[0]`

Comment: Thanks so much. The final step is to substitute your regex in this `/foo|bar|fooba|((?:(?!foo|bar|fooba).)+)/gm`. How can I do?

Comment: That seems unrelated to the question you asked above but you can try: `/(?=(foo))(?=(bar))(?=(fooba))((?:(?!foo|bar|fooba).)+)/`

Comment: Um... pretty sure that: `(?=(foo))(?=(fooba))` will never match just `foo`.