# How to match all possible matches with RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't figure out a way to get all possible matches. For the most basic example I have this:

```
"bbb".match(/bb/g);
//returns ["bb"]
```

but I would like it to return `["bb","bb"]` because `bb` matches with the first two b's and then again with the last 2 b's

In this example the possible matches are identical but they don't have to be for example :

```
"abab".match(/(.{1}).{1}\1/g);
//returns ["aba"]
```

Again here I was hoping for `["aba","bab"]`

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: [How to get all possible overlapping matches for a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029487/how-to-get-all-possible-overlapping-matches-for-a-string)

Comment: [Javascript Regex - Find all possible matches, even in already captured matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863026/javascript-regex-find-all-possible-matches-even-in-already-captured-matches)

Comment: [Regex JavaScript overlapping matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942010/regex-javascript-overlapping-matches)

Comment: [How to get possibly overlapping matches in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34964453/how-to-get-possibly-overlapping-matches-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All matches found by `match(/.../g)` will be non-overlapping: once a match is found, regexp engine continues from the end of the match.

If you want to use this mechanism, you can't use the full match; but you can make use of lookahead and groups, as well as iteration. For example, this will work:

```
re = /bb/g;
var results = [];
while (matches = re.exec("bbb")) {
  results.push(matches);
  re.lastIndex -= matches[0].length - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Overlapping matches can be done by using `positive lookahead` like this.

**Regex:** `(?=(bb))`

**Explanation:**

- It looks ahead for `bb` and captures it. Regex pointer is not at 2nd `b` which again looks ahead and captures `bb`, this time leaving the first one. It continues until end of string.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mH2zK2/1#javascript)**

Comment: It gives output `"bbb".match(/(?=(bb))/);` as `["", "bb"]`

Comment: @gurvinder372: Use back-referencing. Check **Match Information**  section in regex demo. `.match()` returns all the matched subgroups. use `.exec()`

Comment: it looks good in the demo but if you actually try it in javascript with .match and .exec one of the resulting matches is an empty string

Comment: All matches are empty strings in this case; you simulate the match with the first capture group.